# How to load a picture in the ImageView of a collapsing toolbar?

Tags: java, android

I just created an Activity to show some product informations and this Activity has a Collapsing Toolbar. I wanted to load an image by Picasso as soon as the Activity opens.

Here is the current code :

```
public class ProductActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_product);
    Product p = (Product) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("product");
    setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(p.getProductName());

    TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product_name);
    TextView type = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product_type);
    TextView description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product_description);
    TextView ingredients = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product_ingredients);
    TextView price = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product_price);
    ImageView thumbnail = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.product_thumbnail);

    name.setText(p.getProductName());
    type.setText(p.getProductType().getDisplayName());
    description.setText(p.getProductDescription());
    ingredients.setText("Non disponible");
    price.setText(p.getProductPrice().length>1 ? "À partir de "+p.getProductPrice()[0].toString()+"€" : p.getProductPrice()[0].toString()+"€");
    Picasso.with(this).load(p.getProductThumbnailURL()).fit().into(thumbnail);
    Picasso.with(this).load(p.getProductThumbnailURL()).fit().into((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.test), new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {
            Toast.makeText(ProductActivity.this, "Impossible de charger l'image !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId()==android.R.id.home)finish();
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

And here is a screen of the Activity (don't take care of the design xD)

[ProductActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21Yne.jpg)

Any idea ? :p

Comment: share your xml for activity_product

Answer (score 0):

Here is the XML file of the ProductActivity :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.slama.hotpizza77.ProductActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/product_thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:contentDescription="@string/product_thumbnail_string" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="0dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="16dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/product_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="product_name"
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/product_type"
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="product_type"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

                <TextView
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="Description :"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/product_description"
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="product_description"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

                <TextView
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="Ingrédients :"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/product_ingredients"
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="product_ingredients"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_product_pork"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Contient de la viande issue de porc !"
                        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_product_notforkid"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Ne convient pas aux enfants !"
                        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/product_price"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="product_price"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/test"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of wrap_content for your product_thumbnail ImageView height use match_parent or a fixed size.

Hope this helps

Comment: it don't really change anything... I can set an "android:src="" but can't set it by code...

Comment: Are you sure that getProductThumbnailURL give a good image URL ?

Comment: yes x) the object "Product" has a getThumbnailURL() method which return an url given at the registration of the product ;)